# Populate DataGridView [+code]

Tags: c#, datagridview, sqldatareader

Why ths code doesnt populate my DataGridView ?

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        InitializeComponent();


        crud inicializador = new crud();

        tb_GridViewProdutos.DataSource = inicializador.carregarDadosNoForm("tb_Produtos");
        tb_GridViewEstoque.DataSource = inicializador.carregarDadosNoForm("tb_Estoque");
        tb_GridViewUsuarios.DataSource = inicializador.carregarDadosNoForm("tb_Usuario");
        tb_VendasGridView.DataSource = inicializador.carregarDadosNoForm("tb_Venda");

    }

public DataTable carregarDadosNoForm(string opcao)
    {
        Conexao.con.Open(); //Variavel statica definida na classe conexao
        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM "+opcao+"", Conexao.con);
        DataTable data = new DataTable(); //datatable
        SqlDataReader reader = comando.ExecuteReader();
        data.Load(reader);

        Conexao.con.Close();

        return data;

    }
```

I got my Grid's on Form_Load and its return no information from data base.

I have to understand how to use data table, data reader and data adapter.
Can i have a helping hand?!

Comment: I got no errors, just a GridView empty.

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid`, please. Did you set AutoCreateColumns to true?

Comment: Got it. AutoGenerateColumns = true here, but no success :(

Comment: Are there 4 DGVs?  All emtpy? No columns? What about those tables? Are they filled?

Comment: I think i've found the problem. I got the problem because i was using dataSet schema, and i wiped out all data just by clincking and choosing delete from my solution, and then, i have a lot of things in my code that i dont know ... i will create a new one, and teste it again. Thanks man :)

Comment: I don't remember why or what, but I had a lot of problems in the past with DGV ; lots of them got fixed by using a BindingSource between the DataTable and the DGV. You do `bindingSource.DataSource = dataTable;` and then `DGV.DataSource = bindingSource;`